# The simplicity of $\bigwedge^i \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ as a representation of $\mathfrak{sl_{n+1}}$ and its weight vectors

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, multilinear-algebra

I want to show that $\bigwedge^i \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ is a simple representation for $\mathfrak{sl}(n+1,\mathbb{C})$ for each $1\le i \le n+1$ but I'm already stuck at determining the weight vectors.

So let $\mathfrak{h}\subset\mathfrak{sl}(n+1,\mathbb{C})$ be the subalgebra of all diagonal matrices (with trace $0$).

How does an element $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_i$ look like if it satisfies $h(v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_i) = \lambda(h)( v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_i)$ for some $\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*$ and all $h\in \mathfrak{h}$? I cannot come up with any ideas on how to calculate such vectors...

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Do you know how do we get a tensor product of representations for a Lie algebra? Do you then see that the action will descend onto a quotient of the tensor product by an appropriate subspace (to get the $i$ - th exterior power)?

Comment: You should try to find the weights first.  You probably already know all the weight spaces of $V=\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ are one-dimensional.  Now you can pick basis of $V$ accordingly, and now you have basis of $\wedge^i V$, for which you can found out the weight space of each basis.  Hope this gives enough hints.  (You may need some more basic knowledge about wedge product of vector space first).